# dynamic data is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, primereact

Please refer to the sandbox [link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-payne-h9pmpp?file=/src/demo/FileUploadDemo.js)

I'm using my own dynamically generated data and hence using the following in my code:

```
const onRowEditComplete1 = (e) => {
let _dynamicData = [...dynamicData]; 
let { newData, index } = e;
_dynamicData[index] = newData;
setDynamicData(_dynamicData); };
```

And

```
<DataTable
//value={products2} 
 value={data} 
 editMode="row" 
 dataKey="id" 
 onRowEditComplete={onRowEditComplete1} 
 responsiveLayout="scroll">
```

If I try to change the status from `In stock` to `Low stock`, It keeps on throwing `TypeError dynamicData is not iterable` as you can see in the sandbox above.

However, when I change it to the following to use the data from the primereact sandbox example:

```
const onRowEditComplete1 = (e) => {
let _products2 = [...products2]; let { newData, index } = e;
_products2[index] = newData;
setProducts2(_products2);
};
<DataTable
 value={products2}
 editMode="row"
 dataKey="id"
 onRowEditComplete={onRowEditComplete1}
 responsiveLayout="scroll"
 >
```

It doesn't throw any error after editing a row and saving the changes.
How to fix the error in case of the data that I'm using there so that it starts saving properly?

**My complete code if needed for reference:**

```
export const FileUploadDemo = () => {
  const [totalSize, setTotalSize] = useState(0);

  const toast = useRef(null);
  const fileUploadRef = useRef(null);
  //start:Row Editing Work
  const [products2, setProducts2] = useState(null);
  const [dynamicData, setDynamicData] = useState(null);

  const statuses = [
    { label: "In Stock", value: "INSTOCK" },
    { label: "Low Stock", value: "LOWSTOCK" },
    { label: "Out of Stock", value: "OUTOFSTOCK" }
  ];

  const dataTableFuncMap = {
    products2: setProducts2
    //dynamicData: setDynamicData
  };

  const productService = new ProductService();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductData("products2");
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  const fetchProductData = (productStateKey) => {
    productService
      .getProductsSmall()
      .then((data) => dataTableFuncMap[`${productStateKey}`](data));
  };
  const getStatusLabel = (status) => {
    switch (status) {
      case "INSTOCK":
        return "In Stock";

      case "LOWSTOCK":
        return "Low Stock";

      case "OUTOFSTOCK":
        return "Out of Stock";

      default:
        return "NA";
    }
  };

//   const onRowEditComplete1 = (e) => {
//     // console.log("Testing e");
//     // console.log(e);
//     let _products2 = [...products2];
//     let { newData, index } = e;

//     _products2[index] = newData;

//     setProducts2(_products2);
//   };
    const onRowEditComplete1 = (e) => {
        console.log("Testing e")
        console.log(e);
      let _dynamicData = [...dynamicData];
      let { newData, index } = e;

      _dynamicData[index] = newData;

      setDynamicData(_dynamicData);
    };

  const textEditor = (options) => {
    return (
      <InputText
        type="text"
        value={options.value}
        onChange={(e) => options.editorCallback(e.target.value)}
      />
    );
  };
  const statusEditor = (options) => {
    return (
      <Dropdown
        value={options.value}
        options={statuses}
        optionLabel="label"
        optionValue="value"
        onChange={(e) => options.editorCallback(e.value)}
        placeholder="Select a Status"
        itemTemplate={(option) => {
          return (
            <span
              className={`product-badge status-${option.value.toLowerCase()}`}
            >
              {option.label}
            </span>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  const priceEditor = (options) => {
    return (
      <InputNumber
        value={options.value}
        onValueChange={(e) => options.editorCallback(e.value)}
        mode="currency"
        currency="USD"
        locale="en-US"
      />
    );
  };

  const statusBodyTemplate = (rowData) => {
    return getStatusLabel(rowData.inventoryStatus);
  };

  const priceBodyTemplate = (rowData) => {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD"
    }).format(rowData.price);
  };

  //END:Row Editing Work

  const onUpload = (e) => {
    toast.current.show({
      severity: "info",
      summary: "Success",
      detail: "File Uploaded"
    });
    console.log("File Upload event e");
    console.log(e);
    setTotalSize(e.length);
  };

  let data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    data[i] = {
      id: i + 1,
      code: "cm230f032" + i + 1,
      name: "Gaming Set" + i + 1,
      description: "Product Description" + i + 1,
      image: "gaming-set.jpg" + i + 1,
      price: i + 2,
      category: "Electronics" + i + 1,
      quantity: i + 3,
      inventoryStatus: "INSTOCK",
      rating: i + 1
    };
  }

  console.log("Printing Data");
  console.log(data)
//   var result = Object.keys(data).map((key) => [Number(key), data[key]]);

// console.log(result);

  return (
    <div>
      <Toast ref={toast}></Toast>

      <Tooltip target=".custom-choose-btn" content="Choose" position="bottom" />
      <Tooltip target=".custom-upload-btn" content="Upload" position="bottom" />
      <Tooltip target=".custom-cancel-btn" content="Clear" position="bottom" />

      <div className="card">
        <h5>Advanced</h5>
        <FileUpload
          name="demo[]"
          url="https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/upload.php"
          //onUpload={onUpload}
          customUpload
          uploadHandler={onUpload}
          multiple
          accept="image/*"
          maxFileSize={1000000}
          emptyTemplate={
            <p className="m-0">Drag and drop files to here to upload.</p>
          }
        />
      </div>

      <div className="datatable-editing-demo">
        <Toast ref={toast} />

        <div className="card p-fluid">
          <h5>Row Editing</h5>
          <DataTable
            //value={products2}
            value={data}
            editMode="row"
            dataKey="id"
            onRowEditComplete={onRowEditComplete1}
            responsiveLayout="scroll"
          >
            <Column
              field="code"
              header="Code"
              editor={(options) => textEditor(options)}
              style={{ width: "20%" }}
            ></Column>
            <Column
              field="name"
              header="Name"
              editor={(options) => textEditor(options)}
              style={{ width: "20%" }}
            ></Column>
            <Column
              field="inventoryStatus"
              header="Status"
              body={statusBodyTemplate}
              editor={(options) => statusEditor(options)}
              style={{ width: "20%" }}
            ></Column>
            <Column
              field="price"
              header="Price"
              body={priceBodyTemplate}
              editor={(options) => priceEditor(options)}
              style={{ width: "20%" }}
            ></Column>
            <Column
              rowEditor
              headerStyle={{ width: "10%", minWidth: "8rem" }}
              bodyStyle={{ textAlign: "center" }}
            ></Column>
          </DataTable>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<FileUploadDemo />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Noticed that you are not using the data that I'm dynamically generating, could you elaborate please on this?

Comment: Basically I want to use this data and have all the functionality work:`let data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    data[i] = {
      id: i + 1,
      code: "cm230f032" + i + 1,
      name: "Gaming Set" + i + 1,
      description: "Product Description" + i + 1,
      image: "gaming-set.jpg" + i + 1,
      price: i + 2,
      category: "Electronics" + i + 1,
      quantity: i + 3,
      inventoryStatus: "INSTOCK",
      rating: i + 1
    };
  }`

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bird-7tlvhf](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bird-7tlvhf)

Comment: above sandbox seems to be using the data from the json file which I'm not looking for. I'm looking to display data that I am generating as explained in my previous comment. Please let me know if I can answer any questions.

Comment: In my scenario, I won't know in advance how many rows I have to display. Hence I was planning on using seperate `data` variable. How can that be achieved if we use `products2` ?

Comment: _I won't know in advance how many rows I have to display_ ---> In [https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bird-7tlvhf](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-bird-7tlvhf) at line 47: `[...Array(15).keys()].map((i) => ({`. Right now, the number is set to 15. You can change it exactly how you would do with the `for` loop (where you have `i < 4`).

Comment: Please help me understand this. The line # 45 which is  `productService.getProductsSmall().then((data) =>` is not making use of the filr `data/products-small.json` ?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to make use of the static file. What it's currently doing is what I was looking for. Thanks for your response though and time. Appreciated!

Comment: If you are planning to delete above comments with the modified codesandbox answers, if possible please respond to my question as an answer. I will be happy to accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244409/discussion-between-jsn00b-and-tan).